# Identify records with consecutive duplicate values within a string

Tags: sql, hive

I need to identify if a certain string has duplicate values inside. Example, if we have a string "Apple apple Juice" and another that says "Orange Juice", then the code has to pick up the string "Apple apple Juice" because the word "apple" is duplicated.

I am using SQL Workbench HIVE, but REGEXP_LIKE does not work. Also tried the following script:

```
SELECT Fruit_juice
FROM Juice_Warehouse
WHERE Fruit_juice RLIKE '\\b(\\w+)(?:\\W+\\1\\b)+'
```

Would appreciate any kind of suggestion.

Comment: Does your table have only 1 column? Or any ID column lso?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai there are 3 columns -- juice_ID, fruit_name, fruit_juice

Comment: PLease post the sample data and expected output?